# Filter by specific field when webform exports

Tags: 8, webforms

I have a webform with a field_custom field. I need to download the submissions filter by this field.

I saw in the download page this:
[image]

Can I do the same programmatically with a plugin or something else to filter by my field(field_custom)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Webform View Integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_views) and create a custom [Views Data Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export).